# SQLLine login via shell script

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to make a shell script by which I can directly land to sqlline username/password console bypassing the manual login to sqlline. However its failing with below error

```
/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/bin/sqlline.sh -e "!connect jdbc:ignite:thin://node1.example.com:10800,node2.example.com:10800,node3.example.com:10800;sslMode=require;schema=test"
jdbc:ignite:thin://node1.example.com:10800,node2.example.com:10800,node3.example.com:10800;sslMode=require;schema=test (No such file or directory)
Usage: connect <url> <username> <password> [driver]
```

Comment: Don't really understand the rationale of this vs. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/110567994

Comment: @alamar I have two requirement where in first requirement need to login in sqlline console and pass the JDBC connect string to connect Ignite Grid. Whereas in this requirement I want the first process to be be run as in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for the -u flag:

```
/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/bin/sqlline.sh -u "jdbc:ignite:thin://node1.example.com:10800,node2.example.com:10800,node3.example.com:10800;sslMode=require;schema=test"
```

Comment: My main requirement the whole connection process to put in a shell script, where it will run and login sqlline console, then connect to the JDBC string and prompt for username/password.

Comment: What do you mean by "login sqline console"? And "manual login to sqline"? You do not, _cannot_, authenticate with sqline. Are you asking how to pass the username password _for Ignite_ as part of the command?

Comment: I've resolved the issue on my own in different way. Thanks.